# attachments in Send a mail Workflow action

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, workflow-activity, email-templates, designer

Is it possible to attach images as attachments in "send a mail " SharePoint Designer Action?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer No.**

SPD does not allow attachments OOB. MS wants people to send everything as links.

**Long answer Yes.**

You can create your own actions (coding required) or get a third party code which you can find online to create the appropriate action to allow emails to send attachments.

*(This is answer is based on on premise 2013 I assume that online version is no different)*

Comment: thank you .Can you tell me how to create that Custom code ! or give its Link for references.

Comment: @azharuddin This guy has code (2010) for free or follow you can buy 2013 version from his personal site: http://sharepointstuff.codeplex.com/ (2010 free version)